# Exporting Material Components from Library

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-library

I have an angular application with a few libraries. Until now i only had libraries for use with data, but not with components. All material component i need are imported in the application at the moment.

Now i start building a library which uses material components (for example `MatSelect`). So i need to import the `MatSelectModule` into my library.

Should i export the `MatSelectModule`, so that i can use it with any other change in my application? Or should i import the `MatSelectModule` seperately in my application?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking, but if your library requires a material module, you will have to import it into your library.

Comment: Yes, i have to import it in the library. But should i also export it from the library, if i use these components also standalone in the main application?

Comment: You're a step ahead of me - I can't even use material in my library for some reason. However, the answer is yes, why not. There's no harm in exporting other things from your module. Tree shaking and whatever else will determine if any of those additionally exported things are actually used by the modules and thus included or not. It's a nice shorthand so that modules don't necessarily have to directly import things themselves (but they should imo, for clarity if nothing else).